# SSL offloading - Font awesome icons issue

Tags: html, ssl, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, f5

**Environment** - Client -> F5(SSL Enabled) -> Jboss App server(SSL disabled)

**Issue** - Font awesome icons do not appear when I access application via F5 and SSL offloading. It appears fine if I enable SSL on the app servers as well or configure F5 to access through HTTP.

**Observations** - Network gives 403 on the **fontawesome-webfont.ttf**, however the resource is not restricted and does not require authentication. If I hit this URL from browser it downloads ttf file without any issues.

**Additional Information** - Fonts are placed in the application war package and they are referenced by relative path in css file.

Do anyone have ever observed this issue?

**EDIT**

```
*F5 HTTP profile settings*
Request Chunking - Preserve
Response Chunking - Selective
OneConnect Transformations - enabled
Redirect rewrite - all
Send Proxy via header in request/response - Preserve

*F5 SSL profile settings*
Client Certificate - Ignore
Frequency - once
Retain Certificate - enabled
Certificate Chain Traversal Depth - 9
Trusted Certificate Authorities - none
Advertised Certificate Authorities - None
CRL - None
SSL Forward Proxy - Disabled
Certificate Extentions list enabled - Basic Constraints, Subject Alternative Name
Cache Certificate by Addr Port - disabled
```

**EDIT**

Request header

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Languate: en-IE
Authorization Negotiate YIJFAY...
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: selectedTab=#tab-1; JSESSIONID=jVKp...; BIGipServer_Pool=234324.32.000;
Host: abc.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Comment: Are you having any issues loading other resources through the same manner or is it only the fontawesome file? Can you replicate the behaviour on a different directory?

Comment: No, never observed. It could be that you're requesting some files with one Host Header, and the other files with another. Check what you have configured in the Rewrite Profile and the Content HTML Content Profile of your Virtual Server (if any of these profiles are used).

Comment: @webbm - it is only the fontawesome and glyphicon font files that are not getting loaded. Other resources(i.e. images) accessed in the same manner are getting accessed.

Comment: Check for some kind of filetype restriction perhaps? Alternatively, can you post nonsensitive parts of your f5 config?

Comment: Did you check what I said in my 1st comment ? Also, try disabling selinux for some minutes while you can test again.

Comment: @webbm - I dont think there are any filetype restrictions applied, since this is accessible if I enable SSL on app server.

Comment: @EugèneAdell - These profiles are not configured on F5. The only profile configured is HTTP and SSL profile. And the host headers for both the calls are same, the one which is accessible and not accessible. Yes, selinux is enabled, do you think that relates to the filetype restrictions?

Comment: 403 means the file access is denied, as simple as that. Why is it denied, several reasons (my suggestion with F5 profiles was related to bad virtual hosting configuration), it can be related to authentication that you're not aware of, or permissions. It's always a test to do by stopping SELinux temporarily.

Comment: @EugèneAdell - Did test after stopping SELinux, but its still the same.

Comment: For example with FireFox you can run the developer tools and see all requests. Compare the request headers failing with a 403, with the one which is working.

Comment: @EugèneAdell - The headers are almost same, except the difference in Accept attribute to say \*/\* for the one which does not work, whereas for the one that works, it says particular value as well for e.g. image/png, image/*, \*/\*. Also, I have observed that I am able to access the fonts by directly hitting on the URL, however, when observing the header for that, it has accept attribute as image/jxr, \*/\* instead just \*/\*

Comment: Do you know how the JBOSS is configured for Virtual Hosting ? One host catching all traffic, or several (one by domain name) ?

Comment: There are multiple JBOSS configured catching the traffic, with cookie persistence profile.

Comment: I don't know how to help more, sorry. You said there is no difference on client side. So it should be the F5 which is changing something although there is nothing special on the profiles. Do you have a capture made on the JBOSS server showing differences ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell - On the JBOSS servers, I captured tcpdump in both the scenarios. However, they do not show any difference though, except the response 403 v/s 200. At the moment, I have served the [fonts through F5](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/hosting-web-fonts-on-f5-ltm) by adding rule and a file on F5.

Comment: Can you share your captures, at least the header parts (as text) ?